# PS4 USB ports broken and need to run initial system setup, can't use USB cable to sync controller

Tags: controllers, ps4

My questions are; is there any way to sync the controller to the system without the cable on initial setup? Second, would a Micro USB to HDMI MHL Adapter Converter allow me to get the controller synced to the system?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no, would the converter work? i don't think so but i can't give you an answer for it out of experience. Reason why i don't think it wil work is because the HDMI is used for video/audio output in the ps4 menu's